# Is there an eslint rule to enforce types for useState()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I would like to make sure that all our team members properly type their hooks.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User>([]); // --> should work
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]); // --> should throw a linting error
```

So far I couldn't find such a rule. How could I do it myself if there is no existing plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eslint-plugin-require-explicit-generics` looks like what you are looking for.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-require-explicit-generics

to the options you pass name of the functions that you want the generic type to be enforced (eg. `useState` or `React.useState`)